# Can we remove one of the tagged duplicate questions if it is incorrect?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

Very recently (within the last hour or so) a question was asked about the Immutability of Strings in Java. This is the question: [String class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075014/string-class-in-java)

The question has been correctly closed as a duplicate, but it has been tagged as a duplicate of 2 different questions. The two questions are:

1. [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
2. [Immutability of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

I personally do not think that the first duplicate question has anything to do with the original question. It refers to comparing strings, not their immutability.

I'm not suggesting we reopen the question, but I'm wondering if there is a process, or even the ability, to remove the tagged duplicate question that is incorrect.

Comment: Someone with the `java` gold badge could apply Mjölnir twice: once to reopen the question, then once to re-close it against the "right" duplicate.

Comment: Imho, it's not worth the bother: The proper duplicate is there, the other one is not too distracting, and there are an awful lot of questions having greater need of moderation.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. It looks like Frederic's comment is the way to go to get it sorted. I was more curious if it was at all possible. Looks like I'll have to work to get that Java gold badge now.